# Jquery File Upload not working with Gravityforms

Tags: jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to implement  [JQuery File Upload plugin](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html) with Gravity Forms wordpress plugin. I have created a form with file upload input for which Gravity form generated field id like **input_1_33**. I am using this id for file upload jquery plugin.

```
jQuery(function () {
 var url = 'http://localhost/wp-content/themes/testtheme/fileupload/';
 jQuery('#input_1_33').fileupload({
                    replaceFileInput:false,
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    done: function (e, data) {
                        jQuery.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {

                            jQuery('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
                        });
                    },
                    fail:function(e, data){

                    },
                    progressall: function (e, data) {
                        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                        jQuery('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                            'width',
                            progress + '%'
                        );
                    }
                }).prop('disabled', !jQuery.support.fileInput)
                    .parent().addClass(jQuery.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
  });
```

No error was generated in browser console and file is not uploaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a plugin that integrates this with Gravity Forms.

You can find it on the WordPress plugin directory - https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-upload-for-gravity-forms/

And see a demo of it here - http://demo.itsupportguides.com/ajax-upload-for-gravity-forms/

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Great!

Comment: @SrikanthKolli you should not use the deprecated plugins this plugin was deprecated